# How to make lightweight docker image for python app with pipenv

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile, alpine-linux, pipenv

I can produce working image for my python app with following simple `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:3.7
WORKDIR /myapp
COPY Pipfile* ./
RUN pip install pipenv
RUN pipenv install --system --deploy
COPY src .
CMD ["python3", "app.py"]
```

However, it will produce ~1 GB image, which can contain temporary files, and is heavy to deploy. And I only need full python image for building purposes. My app can successfully run on alpine variant, so I can make two-pass `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:3.7 as builder
COPY Pipfile* ./
RUN pipenv lock --requirements > requirements.txt
RUN python3 -m venv /venv
RUN /venv/bin/pip install --upgrade pip
RUN /venv/bin/pip install -r requirements.txt

FROM python:3.7-alpine
COPY --from=builder /venv /venv
WORKDIR /myapp
COPY src .
CMD ["/venv/bin/python3", "app.py"]
```

So far so good, it also works, being 6 times smaller. But this scheme was considered as some "stub", having some drawbacks:

- It has unnesesary extra `COPY --from=builder` step
- It does not utilizes `pipenv` but needs also `pip` for installing (+1 extra step, `pipenv lock`+`pip install` is always slower than just `pipenv install`)
- It does not install system-wide, but into `/venv`, which is to be avoided inside a container
- Minor: Build pollutes intermediate-images cache more, and requires downloading both image variants..

---

How to combine these two approaches, to get lightweitht alpine-based image with `pipenv`, lacking mentioned drawbacks?

Or can you offer your production `Dockerfile` ideas?

Comment: Related question https://stackoverflow.com/q/74211215/11715259

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem comes when you need things like `ciso8601`, or some libraries, requiring build process. Build tools are not "incorporated" into the both `slim` and `alpine` variants, for low-size footprint.

So to install deps, you'll have to:

- Install build tools
- Deploy dependencies from Pipfile.lock system-wide
- Uninstall build tools and clean caches

And do that 3 actions inside a single `RUN` layer, like following:

```
FROM python:3.7-slim

WORKDIR /app

# both files are explicitly required!
COPY Pipfile Pipfile.lock ./

RUN pip install pipenv && \
  apt-get update && \
  apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends gcc python3-dev libssl-dev && \
  pipenv install --deploy --system && \
  apt-get remove -y gcc python3-dev libssl-dev && \
  apt-get autoremove -y && \
  pip uninstall pipenv -y

COPY app ./

CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

- Manipulating build system would cost you around 300MiB and some extra time
- Uninstalling pipenv would save you another 20MiB (which is 10% of resulting size).
- Separating `RUN` commands would not delete data from layers, and would result in ~500MiB image. That's docker specifics.

So that would result in perfectly working ~200MiB sized image, which is

- 5 times less than original `python:3.7`, (that is >1.0GiB)
- Has no alpine incompabilities (these are typically tied to glibc replacement)

At the time, we're fine with `slim` (debian `buster`) build variants, preferring `slim` over `alpine` (for most compatibility). If you're really up to further size optimization, I'd recommend you to take a look at some excellent builds of these guys:

- [Alpine Python](https://hub.docker.com/r/jfloff/alpine-python/#why)
- [12.7MiB MariaDB](https://hub.docker.com/r/jbergstroem/mariadb-alpine/)

Answer (score 8):

How about,

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine

WORKDIR /myapp

COPY Pipfile* ./

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir pipenv && \
    pipenv install --system --deploy --clear

COPY src .
CMD ["python3", "app.py"]
```

1. It utilises the smaller Alpine version.
2. You won't have any unnecessary cache files left over using `--no-cache-dir` option for `pip` and `--clear` option for `pipenv`.
3. You also deploy outside of venv.

You can also add `&& pip uninstall pipenv -y` after `pipenv install --system --deploy --clear` in the same `RUN` command to eliminate space taken by `pipenv` if that extra image size bothers you.

Comment: `pipenv install` would fail, as (in my particular case) it requires full `python:3.7`, for building several packages.. As you may see, it is second step (Am I a fool, using 2-step build, if I can use 1-step?) Btw, thanks for some useful command-line parameters!

Comment: pipenv won’t fail as we are installing pipenv before we invoke it. As for whether you are a fool, how do you think you look making that passive aggressive statement to someone who took time to reply to your question?

Comment: In that particular case `pipenv install` would fail. It required full python:3.7, for building several packages, as well as some libraries that are missing in alpine images. And install-uninstall just leads to slow builds. Anyway we've abandoned and deprecated python developement, in favor of golang. And now we are using fast builds and megabyte-sized images - no need to mess with outdated entry-level slow-working interpreter tool anymore in a modern world. All python code is gone from our projects. Anyway, thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 3):

I am using [micropipenv](https://github.com/thoth-station/micropipenv) for the job, which describes itself as

> A lightweight wrapper for pip to support requirements.txt, Pipenv and Poetry lock files or converting them to pip-tools compatible output. Designed for containerized Python applications but not limited to them.

An image created from it would look like the following.
Since the alpine base image lacks a toml parser we have to use the version of micropipenv that includes the toml extras (`micropipenv[toml]` instead of `micropipenv`).

```
FROM python:3.9-alpine

WORKDIR /myapp
COPY Pipfile Pipfile.lock ./

RUN \
  # Install dependencies
  && pip install --no-cache-dir micropipenv[toml] \
  && micropipenv install --deploy \
  && pip uninstall -y micropipenv[toml]

COPY src .
CMD ["python3", "app.py"]
```

Answer (score 0):

> It has unnecessary extra COPY --from=builder step

That directive is harmless and actually making your final stage image even more lightweight: only the virtualenv is copied, no building toolchains nor cached wheels nor even pipenv in the final stage!

> It does not utilizes pipenv but needs also pip for installing (+1 extra step, pipenv lock+pip install is always slower than just pipenv install)

Generate the virtualenv with pipenv in the building stage!

```
FROM python:3 as builder
COPY Pipfile* /
RUN mkdir /.venv  # The presence of a .venv folder triggers pipenv to use it by default
RUN pipenv install --deploy

FROM python:3-slim
COPY --from=builder /.venv /.venv
WORKDIR /myapp
COPY src .
CMD ["/.venv/bin/python3", "app.py"]
```

> It does not install system-wide, but into /venv, which is to be avoided inside a container

While not using venvs inside docker is a common practice, there are still some benefits to them. And absolute 0 drawbacks. Stop listening to people saying venvs should not be used inside dockers. Pipenv current recommendation is to not issue system-wide installs in containers https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/pull/2762

> Minor: Build pollutes intermediate-images cache more, and requires downloading both image variants..

Simply optimize your caches setup in the CI system.

BUT

**For the love of God use the same platform for the building and final stages.**

Either

- use `python:3-alpine` for both stages, bloating the building stage with as many `apk` packages as you need
- settle for `python:3` for building and `python:3-slim` for the final stage. It is not that big

Alpine images use `musl` instead of `libc` and that means a different ABI for python packages https://peps.python.org/pep-0656/. Do not mix alpine images with non-alpine images just as you would not mix python:3.A images with a different python:3.B.

Otherwise some of the components installed in the building stage **will** be unusable by the final stage.

Answer (score 0):

My solution **does not use pipenv**, however, it builds a really lightweight base image using an intermediate Ubuntu stage to install system dependencies and later copy the output to the final python image.

My application needs to run on `debian based ubuntu OS` with `python3.7`.

Though I'm still exploring, the application runs without issues.

Without using Ubuntu to install system dependencies, the output image from `python:3.7-slim` was more than `700-800 MB`, after this, it is barely `350-400 MB`.

```
# Build Python packages through an intermediate stage based on ubuntu.
FROM ubuntu:20.04 as builder
RUN apt-get update -y
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractives

# Install system dependencies required to install a few python packages
# These could be different based on the python package you want to install
RUN apt-get install wget -y
RUN apt-get install libtool build-essential autoconf automake pkg-config libtool-bin -y
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y cmake python3-dev

# In my case, I need the python packages `fb-re2` & `zeromq`
RUN apt-get install -y libre2-dev
# Install system dependency for `libzmq`
WORKDIR /zeromq
RUN wget -O zeromq-4.3.2.tar.gz https://github.com/zeromq/libzmq/releases/download/v4.3.2/zeromq-4.3.2.tar.gz &&\
    tar -xzf zeromq-4.3.2.tar.gz
WORKDIR /zeromq/zeromq-4.3.2
RUN ./autogen.sh && ./configure && make && make install


# Update package lists and install necessary dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    software-properties-common \
    && add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa

# Install Python 3.7 and pip
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    python3.7 \
    python3.7-dev \
    python3-pip \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Set python3.7 as the default python
RUN ln -s /usr/bin/python3.7 /usr/bin/python
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install python3.7-distutils -y
RUN apt-get install locate tcpdump -y
RUN python -m pip install --no-binary=:all: pyzmq==18.0.2
RUN python -m pip install fb-re2

# Install a couple of other python libraries
RUN python -m pip install --no-binary=:all: psutil==5.6.7
RUN python -m pip install --no-binary=:all: netifaces==0.11.0

### Final image build ###
# Build the base image for python based applications like a webserver.
FROM python:3.7.16-slim-buster

### From the intermediate build stage, copy the generated outputs to our final python image
COPY --from=builder /usr/local/lib/libzmq* /usr/local/lib
COPY --from=builder /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/zmq/ /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/zmq
COPY --from=builder /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pyzmq-18.0.2.egg-info/ /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyzmq-18.0.2.egg-info

COPY --from=builder /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/psutil/ /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psutil
COPY --from=builder /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/netifaces* /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libre2-dev
COPY --from=builder /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/*re2* /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/
COPY --from=builder /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/fb_re2-1.0.7.dist-info/ /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fb_re2-1.0.7.dist-info
## END of copying from intermediate ubuntu stage

WORKDIR /my/work/dir/
COPY requirements.txt .

# Install other python packages through requirements.txt
# It will disregard any package installation failure
# Logs can later be found in `/var/log/python_package_installation.log` inside the container
RUN set -e && cat requirements.txt | xargs -n 1 pip install > /var/log/python_package_installation.log 2>&1 || true

EXPOSE 18000
# Let's run a simple python server, so that we can go to the
# container's shell and debug ourselves
CMD python3 -m http.server
```