# Workflow for building python wheels in a multistage dockerfile with pipenv

Tags: docker, dockerfile, pipenv, docker-multi-stage-build, binary-reproducibility

In order to keep final docker image small, my usual approach to building python projects with binary dependencies is to build the pinned dependencies in a first stage and copy them to a final stage lacking the building toolchains. Broadly:

```
FROM python:3 as builder
RUN apt-get install -y libfoo-dev libbar-dev
COPY constraints.txt /
RUN pip wheel \
  --constraint /constraints.txt \
  --wheel-dir /wheels \
  python-foo pyBar

FROM python:3-slim
RUN apt-get install -y libfoo libbar
COPY requirements.txt constraints.txt /
COPY --from=builder /wheels /wheels
RUN pip install \
  --requirement /requirements.txt \
  --constraint /constraints.txt \
  --only-binary :all: \
  --find-links /wheels
```

Now I am trying to something similar on a project managed with pipenv and I am quite astray on how to achieve the same effect: pre-building the few projects that lack a public wheel in a first stage for the version pinned in the lockfile, and use them in a later `pipenv install --deploy` in the final stage.

Does this even make sense with the hash checking pipenv does? Is there any alternative to reduce the final image size? I'd like to avoid using a private index where to store prebuilt wheels, I'd rather keep the solution contained in the Dockerfile.

Related question [How to make lightweight docker image for python app with pipenv](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58300046/11715259)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution is to install a full virtualenv and copy it, not only some wheels.

```
FROM python:3 as builder
RUN apt-get install -y libfoo-dev libbar-dev
RUN pip install pipenv
WORKDIR /app
COPY Pipfile* /app
RUN mkdir /app/.venv
RUN pipenv install --deploy

FROM python:3-slim
RUN apt-get install -y libfoo libbar
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=builder /app/.venv /app/.venv
ENV PATH=/app/.venv/bin:$PATH
```